# PUBNUB here_now returning wrong channel list

Tags: javascript, pubnub

I have subscribed with new channel as well as new publish_key and sub_key where I want to see complete channel list with these keys,So I am using

```
PUBNUB.here_now({
uuids:true,
callback:function(w){
console.log(w);
}
});
```

And it is returning 1300 channels with thousands of occupacy where it should return channels list with two channels because I am subscribed with only two channels.

you can check this with developer console also.

Please provide me solution why it is happening so?

Comment: Shubham, you should report these sorts of issues directly to support@pubnub.com - please submit this to that email and provide your sub-key. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

finally,I got the solution while scretching head all the day ,When i explored library I came to know that If we are providing values to PUBNUB.init() and we are storing its intstance it will take 'demo' as there keys

For example :

```
 PUBNUB.init({
    publish_key://my publish key,
    subscribe_key://my subscrition key
 });
```

then

```
PUBNUB.here_now({
   uuids:true,
   callback:function(e){
   console.log(e);
  }
});
```

It will return values according to 'demo' keys because you PUBNUB.init() returns instance which is pointing to some SELF function of library so if you are not calling methods with returning instance it will return values according to 'demo' keys otherwise not.
Have a look

```
var pubnub=PUBNUB.init({
    publish_key://my publish key,
    subscribe_key://my subscrition key
  });
```

then

```
pubnub.here_now({
    uuids:true,
    callback:function(e){
    console.log(e);
   }
 });
```

Where according to it should return error if you are not using PUBNUB instance because it may confuse developer why he is not getting right values unless he will not explore library code.

Comment: Shubham, you are very keen to have figured this out. It is very subtle. The demo keys are default when you use the PUBNUB reference. I do agree this is confusing. I was meant to be a convenience for getting started. We will make our docs and sample apps more clear going forward. Thanks again for pointing this out. Cheers!